# Has the nomination banner disappeared from the main site?

Tags: support, election

On the main site, the community moderator banner has disappeared. I can still see it on the meta site and access the election..but is it taken down or just my PC glitching up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All banners are limited to 48 hours except during the "birth" of a new site. This is by design.

The [featured meta election topic](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361/2011-community-moderator-election) is the permalink on the main site.

(oh, and meta posts can only be featured for 30 days, after which the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag is stripped automatically to prevent staleness.)

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up; but why would this be exactly? I can understand for things like 'the site is being cleaned up', but I would've thought there would be a special category for things like that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like system messages can only stay up for 2 days.  I re-added it for now, but I suspect that it's a bug.